# Use the address in the database for imageview

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-imageview

I'm sorry for my English .

I have a SQLite database of stored name of images in the drawable folder.

Example : R.drawable.image1 , R.drawable.image2 , ...

Is there a way that addresses stored in the database attributed to ImageViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get a Drawable by it's name, but it needs to be the full name of the resource, including the extension. So, for instance, if "R.drawable.image1" refers to an image named "image1.png", you will need to look it up by the string "image1.png".

Given the name of the image (e.g. "image1"), you can use the following method to get the resource id of the image (assuming that all of your images have the ".png" extension):

```
private final Map<String, Integer> iconMap = new HashMap<>();

public int getIconResourceId(final String imageName) {
    String name = imageName.replace(".png", "");

    Integer resourceId = iconMap.get(name);

    if(resourceId == null) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
        iconMap.put(name, resourceId); // cache the entry
    }

    return resourceId.intValue();
}
```

Note that the above code caches the resource ids - I use this in code for a RecyclerView, where the same image may need to be retrieved often, while scrolling the RecyclerView. If you don't need that, you may want to remove the HashMap.